# S1 server side detection method explanation

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, url, parameters

I found the following method for [S1 server side detection on github](https://gist.github.com/TehNrd/9242970):

```
//Determin if this is SF1 app
public static Boolean isSF1(){
    if(!Utils.checkNullOrBlank(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sfdcIFrameHost')) ||
        !Utils.checkNullOrBlank(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sfdcIFrameOrigin')) ||
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('isdtp') == 'p1' ||
        (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL') != null && ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL').contains('projectone') )
    ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

It does the trick and is a very handy piece of code.

However, I can't seem to find any explanation of the parameters it's checking:

1. `sfdcIFrameHost`
2. `sfdcIFrameOrigin`
3. `isdtp`
4. `projectone`

Does anyone know anything about these parameters?

Comment: They are various parameters regarding embedded pages. Technically, they are "internal use only", but we ingenious developers often leverage internal parameters to great effect.

Comment: Cheers @sfdcfox, much appreciated! I was really hoping for some official Saleforce documentation on them, but as seems to be the case with almost everything S1 related, developers are hacking and slashing their way through on their own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to give a true explanation as Salesforce hasn't released that so we can only guess.

`isdtp` appears to be used to define how the page is rendered:
[www.ca-peterson.com/2011/11/magic-isdtp-param.html](http://www.ca-peterson.com/2011/11/magic-isdtp-param.html)

`sfdcIFrameOrigin` and `sfdcIFrameHost` seem to be two parameters passed on mobile only (at this time).
`sfdcIFrameOrigin` is probably used to resolve some cross site scripting issues.
`sfdcIFrameHost` when I inspected it in the desktop version of the one app was set to `web` whereas from the mobile device it was set to `hybrid` so I guess it helps the app determine what type of environment it is in.